# Saving Opencv Images

Tags: opencv

Hi I have a window running in OpenCV (C API)  and I would like to save a series of images from the window without saving over the previous image.  So after a certain time the window should save refresh, then save and refresh etc. and I should have multiple images on my computer.  I haven't quite gotten there but I am trying to do something like:

```
if (counter>=300)  {
int counterimg=1;
//reset background to black
cvSet(imgScribble,cvScalar(0,0,0);
//save image to file 
cvSaveImage("/Documents/testframe.jpg" [counterimg], frame); 
counter=0;
//increase counter for saving
counterimg+=1;  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to create a path name with the index of the image:

```
char path[512];
snprintf(path, 512, "/Documents/testframe%03d.jpg", counterimg);
cvSaveImage(path, frame);
```

The "%03d" will be replaced by "000", "001", "002", etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help but this is saving only 001 and not incrementing

Comment: And also testframe310720 :?

Comment: I guess you realized, because my comment is a bit late, but you just need to do `counterimg++;` to obtain different numbers.

Answer (score 0):

An example for saving image to file with incremental name, like `capture001.jpg`, `capture002.jpg`, `capture003.jpg`,etc.

```
char path[255];
char num[10];
char jpg[10] = ".jpg";
int counter = 0;

while (1) {
    // To save 20 images
    if (counter < 20) {
        strcpy(path, "c:\\capture");
        sprintf(num, "%03i", counter);
        strcat(path, num);   
        strcat(path, jpg);
        printf("Saving: %s\n", path);
        cvSaveImage(path, frame);
        counter++;
    }
    // Press ESC to break loop
    char ch = waitKey(25);              
    if (ch == 27) break;
}
```