# How to make all images of same size and write them in a folder

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to convert different sizes of images from my different folders to the same size as defined in the width and height and them save them in different folder or replace them, I use the function `cv::resize` for it, and surely `imwrite` may be use for saving them, but its not working for me, as it showing me error in the parameters of resize.

```
int count = 0;
int width = 144;
int height = 33;
vector<string>::const_iterator i;
string Dir;
for (i = all_names.begin(); i != all_names.end(); ++i)
{
    Dir=( (count < files.size() ) ? YourImagesDirectory_2 : YourImagesDirectory_3);

    Mat row_img = cv::imread( Dir +*i, 0 );

    cv::resize(row_img , width , height);
    imwrite( "D:\\TestData\\img_resize.jpg", img_resize );

    ++count;
}
```

After resize this function :

```
imwrite( "D:\\TestData\\img_resize.jpg", img_resize );
```

Only save one image to my folder test , i want all of them in my folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way through which i can csave multiple images in the folder :

```
for (i = all_names.begin() ; i!= all_names.end() ; i++)
    {
        Dir=( (count < files.size() ) ? YourImagesDirectory : YourImagesDirectory_2);
        Mat row_img = cv::imread(Dir+*i );
        //imshow ("show",row_img);
        Mat img_resize;
        resize(row_img, img_resize, Size(144, 33));
        Mat img = img_resize;
        sprintf(buffer,"D:\\image%u.jpg",count);
        imwrite(buffer,img);
        //imwrite("D:\\TestData\\*.jpg" , img_resize);
        count++;
    }
```

Use the functions :

```
sprintf(buffer,"D:\\image%u.jpg",count);
imwrite(buffer,img);
```

For giving directory , name and imwrite for saving there

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for how to [resize](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=resize#cv.Resize) an image:

```
Mat img = imread("C:\\foo.bmp");
Mat img_resize;
resize(img, img_resize, Size(144, 33));
```

**EDIT:**

Supposed that you have several images named as `image001.jpg`, `image002.jpg`, `image003.jpg`, `image004.jpg`, `image005.jpg`..., and want to save them after resizing. Hopes the following code works it out.

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
using namespace cv;

char pathLoading[255];
char pathSaving[255];
char num[10];
char jpg[10] = ".jpg";
int counter = 1;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    while (1) {
        if (counter < 6) {
            // To load 5 images
            strcpy(pathLoading, "c:\\image");
            sprintf(num, "%03i", counter);
            strcat(pathLoading, num);   
            strcat(pathLoading, jpg);
            Mat image = imread(pathLoading);
            Mat image_resize;
            resize(image, image_resize, Size(144, 33));
            // To save 5 images
            strcpy(pathSaving, "c:\\image_resize");
            sprintf(num, "%03i", counter);
            strcat(pathSaving, num);   
            strcat(pathSaving, jpg);
            imwrite(pathSaving, image_resize);
            counter++;          
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How to write all the images in a folder ?

Comment: @Ahmad Do you mean to load all the images from one folder? Are the files' names all consecutive or totally different?

Comment: no , i want to save the images after `resize` in a folder name "Test" `or` images can be save into the same folder from where they read or images can rewrite , in any way my concern is only saving them in my system

Comment: this function work for me , but it rewrite the images : `imwrite( "D:\\TestData\\img_resize.jpg", img_resize );`

Comment: @Ahmad Of course your files names in `imwrite()` should be different everytime when you save them. Is that ok to name them like `image001.jpg`, `image002.jpg`, `image003.jpg`, etc? If so, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18228258/saving-opencv-images/18234313#18234313 for reference. (`imwrite` works same as `cvSaveImage`, the former one is C++ API)

Comment: Yes , i have no problems with the name of the images

Comment: the link you give me is in C format , i am new to opencv , i can't convert it into c++ interface

Answer (score 0):

If the only goal is to resize the images I would guess it would be simpler to use dedicated software with batch processing capability, e.g. IrfanView.

If this is programming exercise, nevermind my answer and look at answers by other people.

HINT: You are saving all your images with single filename, thus effectively rewriting the previously converted images with the new ones.